# Clothing workflow: Kimono - symmetrical clothing, different positions on each side

Tags: cloth-simulation

**NOTE:** this is the "header" of a series of questions, so the beginning is the same for every question and all the others will link to that one as reference.

Another Blender newbie here, and in trouble.

I chose a samurai-like character as the final project of my Blender course, and went through almost every step: from sculpting to retopo, UV, materials, multires sculpt, baking, hair particles, etc, I went through almost every step, suffered a lot and learned even more, but on the clothing part I might be reaching my limit because I don't know the right order of doing what I need to.

In this case, the clothing is similar to an open robe or kimono tightened by a cloth belt.

More or less like this (the coat isn't a problem since it comes after the hard part),

[image]

or this sans the shoulder part (I hope)

[image]

Almost every guide on clothing simulator on youtube works with either clothing with only two pieces (front and back) or fully symmetrical.

I read most of the wiki, watched at least one hour of video guides, got the ideas behind basic material properties, adding collision, baking and applying the modifier in the right frame, etc. But some things are just hard for me to organize in the head.

## Now to the question parts:

1 - How do I make the cloth fold asymmetrically (one side below and another above the other)? Do I manage each of the "halves" as a separate piece of clothing? can I make parts of the simulation move with different properties from the rest?

Comment: Please narrow down your question to a specific problem, and keep one question per post; ask as many as necessary. As it stands your question is too broad to be answerable in this format.

Comment: Ok: rewriting and reposting soon